# Query with conditional AND condition

Tags: react-native, sqlite

Fields `status`, `trade`, `department`, `urgency_level` and `room` I want to filter from (all are optional). My query:

```
let queryParams = '';
let filterOptions : IFilterProps = params.filterOptions;
if (filterOptions.status && filterOptions.status != '-1') {
  queryParams = `status = '${filterOptions.status}'`
}
if (filterOptions.priority && filterOptions.priority != '0') {
  queryParams = queryParams + `AND urgency_level = '${filterOptions.priority}'`
}
if (filterOptions.department) {
  queryParams = queryParams + `AND work_type = '${filterOptions.department}'`
}
if (filterOptions.trade) {
  queryParams = queryParams + `AND location = '${filterOptions.trade}'`
}
if (filterOptions.room) {
  queryParams = queryParams + `AND room_id = '${filterOptions.room}'`
}

selectQuery = await GetDataFromLocalDataBase('SELECT * FROM MaintenancesHistory WHERE '+queryParams, []);

export const GetDataFromLocalDataBase = (sql, params = []) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 db.transaction((tx) => {
  tx.executeSql(sql, params, (tx, results) => {
    resolve(results);
 },
   (error) => {
    reject(error);
    });
   });
 });
```

When I choose `department` only, query will be `AND work_type = 'Housekeeping'`. How can I concatenate all possible combinations?